# The className doesn't get added to the HTML element with this function, Why?

Tags: javascript

```
function manipulateClass(elementName, className, operation) {
    const elementLoader = document.getElementById(elementName);
    if(operation === 'add') { 
        if(!elementLoader.classList.contains(className)) { 
            elementLoader.classList.add(className); 
        } 
    }

    if(operation === 'remove') { 
        if(elementLoader.classList.contains(className)) { 
            elementLoader.classList.remove(className); 
        } 
    }
};

manipulateClass('someId', 'someClass', 'add');
```

The class doesn't get added to the HTML element when I inspect the page, why is that?

EDIT: Code works fine! My bad!

Comment: any error in console ?

Comment: Maybe you are calling `manipulateClass` before element with id "someId" is loaded into the dom? Maybe there isn't element with such id even if dom is loaded before you call this function. Please provide [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: No, the console is clear.

Comment: @Danko I wrap this code in a window.onload = function( ) { }, it is in React so I am not sure how to provide an example but working on it

Comment: I edited your question to put the code into a runnable snippet but had to cancel it because it was working just fine. The error must be somewhere else.

Comment: it works fine for me too.

Comment: If you are using React, better to se `useEffect` or `componentDidMount` than `window.onload = function( ) { }`

Answer (score 0):

Ah figured it out.
I was using React, and wrapping it in a window.onload function, but I was doing that in a template js file I was exporting.

When I added the same code to the main App.js, it worked just fine.

Sorry if my question seemed chaotic! (first time using the platform)
Thanks for everyone that took the time to check it!